# python manage.py runserver - Doesnt work in Django project

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I started my first project with Django framework (Window platform).
When trying to run manage.py runserver, i received an Error.
Python version - 3.8.5 , Django version - 3.1

I am attaching the Error i received in the Terminal

```
(venv) C:\Users\shai.QIL\PycharmProjects\djangoProject>python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\shai.QIL\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\shai.QIL\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\shai.QIL\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\shai.QIL\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\shai.QIL\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 177, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\shai.QIL\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\shai.QIL\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\djangoProject\settings.py", line 57, in <module>
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `import os` in the `manage.py`

Comment: not to `manage.py`, but to `settings.py` (although iirc the `import` statement is already in the default settings file - perhaps the OP removed it?)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `import os` in your **settings.py**

Comment: I did, right after i posted it. It solved the issues, no Error anymore.

Comment: I see, no worries Shai